# Converting KML with multiple layers to Shapefiles?

Tags: pyqgis, kml

I have a KML-file (available [here](https://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS-2/obs/map/world_asc/kml/A_Cycle06.kml)). It has several polygon paths for Alos/Palsar images.

I am in need to convert all these files from KML to shapefile, saving the layers using the layer `"ID"`.

I am trying to use the piece of code bellow (PyQGIS), but I do not know how to unzip this KML and save the shapefiles using the layer `"ID"` information

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("D:/KML-Images/A_Cycle06.kml", "line", "ogr")

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer, "D:/KML-Images/<layer ID>.shp", "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: A_Cycle06.kml isn't a zip file, it looks like a regular KML (XML) file.

Comment: Hi @mmtoken, but even though the tasks bellow are not doing the right convertion vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("D:/KML-Images/A_Cycle06.kml", "polygon", "ogr")

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer, "D:/KML-Images/A_Cycle06.shp", "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")

Answer (score 1):

Run QGIS 3.4 and higher,

then Layer> Add layer> Add vector layer choose path> add see figure 1.

[image]

Then select files in parts, just don’t choose to select all,

see result figure 2,

[image]

they are grouped, then save to *.shp

I think that the problem of processing the grouped file you provided is *.KML is that each individual file has a field value of ID = 1, which causes the program to "hang", perhaps something else ...